How convert yolox onnx to yolox dlc
Trying to convert ONNX to DLC training YOLOX model. When ONNX its working but converting dlc doesnt work

YOLOX trained model --> convert .ONNX --> ONNXRUNTIME --> decode --> Visualization == Work
YOLOX trained model --> convert .ONNX(include decode) --> ONNXRUNTIME --> Visualization == Work

But when converting to .dlc model it doesnt work

YOLOX trained model --> convert .ONNX --> convert .dlc --> snpe-det-run --> decode --> Visualization == not Work
YOLOX trained model --> convert .ONNX(include decode) --> convert .dlc --> snpe-det-run --> Visualization == not Work

Score also doent apply Sigmoid. I dont know Why :(
ONNX Result

DLC Result

YOLOX/demo/ONNX/onnx_infernece
snpe-net-run
Can visualize dlc model result
